# How to run for loop in debug mode within RStudio?

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio

I have the following Code to get a reproducible error:

```
cc <- function(){
  a(2)  
}

a <- function(b){

  x <- rep(NA, 3)
  for(nr in 1:3){
    x[nr] <- nr
  }
  a*2

}

cc()
```

(Note that this is a sample error, i am not interested to solve. It is just a minimal reproducible example that allows me to have an example where we get in debug mode).

I use RStudio with the Debugging Settings: "Break in Code" (Debug - On Error - Break in Code).

While Debugging i want to run the for loop but i can`t:

```
> cc()
Error in a * 2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
Called from: a(2)
Browse[1]> x <- NULL
Browse[1]> for(nr in 1:3){
+     x[nr] <- nr
+   }
debug at #2: x[nr] <- nr
Browse[4]> x
NULL
```

**Question:**

How can i run for-loops, if Statements, while, etc. in debug mode (and store the corresponding results in the "debugging Environment")?

(To be precise i can run the Code, as one can see in the example above. But the value of x does not Change).

**Edit: Why would i want this?**

Sometimes i hit an unexpected error in my Code and to better understand it i wish to execute the Code before / after that specific "error part" of my code. This works great, except that the results of running the for loop are not saved to the "temporary debug Environment" as shown in the example.

So replacing the for loop with sapply or similar would not solve it as the same challenge holds for while, if, etc.

**What i tried:**

- `browser()` one can set within a for loop. But i would not want to set it beforehand
  . I also dont Need to break at a certain Point of that for loop?.
- using `recover()`

I would expect that the Content within a loop is not an additional Environment i would be able to Access via `recover()`,...

Attempt to follow James Curran´s solution:

```
> debug(cc)
> cc()
debugging in: cc()
debug at
 #1: {
    a(2)
}
Browse[2]> debug(a)
Browse[2]> a(2)
debugging in: a(2)
debug at #1: {
    x <- rep(NA, 3)
    for (nr in 1:3) {
        x[nr] <- nr
    }
    a * 2
}
Browse[4]> x <- rep(NA, 3)
Browse[4]> for(nr in 1:3){
+     x[nr] <- nr
+   }
debug at #2: x[nr] <- nr
Browse[5]> a*2
Error in a * 2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
Browse[7]> x
[1] NA NA NA
```

I dont seem to have changed X, (I hope i followed the instructions correctly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this try?

```
> debug(a)
> cc()
```

In this way, the debug starts to work only in a function.
[image: ps]

Comment: thats a great lead thank you! I manage to run through the loop with keyboard shortcut `s` and finish loop with `f`. But i am not sure i do the correct procedure:  If i run Code --> Code has an error and i am in debug mode. Do i have to stop the debug mode - run `debug(functionName)`? Or is there a "direct" way without leaving debug mode and rerun?

Comment: I didn't get how yours code look like and what you'd like to debug

Comment: Given the example in the Question, lets assume i dont know that there is an error in `a()`. So if i run `cc()` i would be in debug mode, without having `debug(a)` called. How can i apply your solution the fastest now? Exit debug mode, run `debug(a)` and re-run the Code or is there a faster solution?

Comment: I am not familiar with a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Use the `debug` function in R. Before you call `cc` execute

```
debug(cc)
```

Then call `cc`. Once you enter `cc` in debug mode, you probably want to debug `a` as well, so type

```
debug(a)
```

And proceed.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, it seems I dont seem to have changed x, (I hope i followed the instructions correctly?). See me edit above

Comment: The error is coming from the line `a * 2`. What were you hoping this for this to do? As it reads, you are multiplying your function `a` by `2` which doesn't make sense.

Comment: this is just to get a reproducible error. My Goal is to run the for loop in debug mode not to solve the actual error. I tried to create a reproducible example with an error, instead of copying the hundreds/thousands lines of my actual Code,...Can you run the for loop in debug mode?

Comment: Yes, you can run a loop in debug mode. However, two things 1/ It is often a lot slower and 2/ if you want to break inside that loop, then you'll probably need a `browser()` call. I see from your question that you don't want `browser` called. I am guessing it is because you want to break the loop at a certain point? A simple way to do that is to put conditional code, e.g. `if(nr==2)browser()`

Comment: thanks for the Response. You are Right, i dont want browser to be called and also dont want to break at a certain Point. Sometimes i just want to execute parts  of a function to better understand the Code before / after the error, but cant execute the for loops,...